# New to JavaScript and have a basic problem

Tags: javascript

I am new to web programming and am having a problem calling a JavaScript function on a form button click. Instead of calling the function and executing the alert() it will reload the page, and reset the data that was entered into the text boxes. I am sure this is a simple error, but I am having trouble figuring this one out.

This is the code I have for my HTML form button

```
<input type="button" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" onclick="submit()" value="Submit Answer" />
```

And this is the function I am calling, without success

```
function submit(){
    alert("working");
    var answer=document.getElementById(answerText).value;
    alert(answer);
    if(movieArrayRand[0].answer==answer)
        {
            alert("You Win");
        }
    else{alert("You Lose");}
}
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Where are `answerText` and `movieArrayRand` defined?

Comment: answerText is another form element I have defined, and movieArrayRand is an array declared in an earlier function. There could be an issue with that code, I just don't understand why the alert() wouldn't even be working.

Comment: @user494216 it would be helpful if you could show the snippet of code where you define `answerText` and `movieArrayRand`. We need more context to help you out. :)

Comment: Might be a long-shot but i hear that sarafi doesn't like you using the keyword 'submit()' as it will execute it and submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the javascript function is named something other than submit() the alert will be called (that is the re-named function will then be called when the button is clicked - submit is a function of the form object so there's an ambiguity I believe and you're seeing it being called rather than your javascript code)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return false` on that form element if you want to catch the submit and "validate" it with your JS function.

Then, the basic concept is that if the form is valid, you use AJAX to submit the form from your validate JS function.

Add an attribute of onSubmit = "return false"` to that form element. So your form element  would look something like this:

```
<form onSubmit = "return false">
```

With more attribute definitions of course.

Comment: I shouldn't need AJAX because this is for a class and we have not learned it yet. I actually have a button that calls a function earlier in the program and it works fine. This one doesn't for some reason.

Comment: OK. I'll reevaluate my answer. :)

Comment: I added the onSubmit="return false" to my form element but the page is still reloading when I call submit(). My form now looks like this:

 "'"<form name="gameForm" onSubmit="return false">
   <p><input name="hintText" size=60></textarea></p>
   <p>Scrambled Word:</p>
   <p><input name="scrambleAnswer" size=30></textarea></p>
   <p>Answer Text:</p>
   <p><input name="answerText" size=30></textarea></p>
   <input type="button" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" onclick="submit()" value="Submit Answer" />
  </form>"'"